# Hover FadeIn FadeOut

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to create a hover over action which brings in a coloured image and also once the hover is removed it fades back to its original image.

Currently it fades out the image to nothing and then fades the new one in. This will then stay in place regardless of whether i hover off or no.

```
//Loop through the images and print them to the page
   for (var i=0; i < totalBoxes; i++){
    $.ajax({
     url: "random.php?no=",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
      // following line I originally suggested, but let's make it better...
      //$('#bg').append(html).fadeIn('slow');
      // also note the fine difference between append and appendTo.
      var $d = $(html).hide().appendTo('#bg').fadeIn('slow');
      $('img', $d).hover(function() {
       var largePath = $(this).attr("rel");
       $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).attr({ src: largePath }).fadeIn("slow");
       });
      });
     }
    });
   }
```

#### Update:

Please take a look at this link:

> http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/index.php#

I am trying to get the images to cross fadein on rollover and out on fadeout...

Can anyone help, im so close and i have spent hours and hours trying to get my head around this...

Comment: So you're wanting to have the black and white image fade into color on mouseover, then go back on mouseout? Right now it's switching, then fading out and back in on mouseover.

Comment: yeh exactly right coreyward...i feel like im causing people alot of grief over this which i hate...

Comment: Since you want a crossfade just fade your front image.  Don't worry about fading the black and white image.

Comment: I merged two of your duplicate questions into one.  In the future, please edit your questions when you have new information so we can keep it all in one place.  Thanks, and welcome to SO.

Comment: Andy -- I updated my answer with all the code you should need -- check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks to you all for your help...i got somewhere...i am not totally happy as its slower than i originally intended because im loading two images in now as apposed to one...using the rel attribute made it alot quicker becaue i was loading the image only on hover...

But here is a solution thanks to you all...

```
          //Loop through the images and print them to the page
        for (var i=0; i < totalBoxes; i++){
            $.ajax({
                url: "random.php?no=",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {

                    var $d = $(html).hide().appendTo('#bg').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#colour img').css("opacity", 0);
                    $('img', $d).hover(function() { 
                        $(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 1);
                    },function() {
                        $(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 0);
                    });

                }
            });
        }
```

and my php prints...

```
<div class="pf-box">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="black"><img src="'.$image_folder.'/'.$image_name.'.jpg" alt="'.$image_name.'" border="0" /></div>
    <div class="colour"><img src="'.$image_folder.'/'.$image_name.'-c.jpg" alt="'.$image_name.'" border="0" /></div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: What part do you find slow?  The initial load or the hovering?

Comment: loading in is slow because im loading two images...before i was trying to load one then use the rel attribute to load the second only when it was hovered which gave a much smoother fade in one after the other when you first load the page.

Comment: If you want the initial fade in to be quick then just change fadeTo(700,1) to something faster like fadeTo(100,1)

Comment: no sorry i mean when it appends the images to the page i have it fading in...so it loops through pulls and image from random then appends to the page using fade.  Before it was really swift but now its clunky because im bring two images from the random page as apposed to referencing the rel attribute on hover to swap the image...

Comment: ah, so it's the initial pageload that you're worried about -- for that I would not iterate over your ajax call.  That's way too much overhead.  Call your ajax once and have it return an array of all possible images then repeatedly pull random images from that array in javascript.

Comment: Thanks aaron for talking to me about this...ill tell you why i did it this way because when i resize the window its going to run the javascript function and add more boxes if necessary based on the viewport height and width...therefor if i had an array it would already be predefined which would mean when resizing i would have a blank space.

Comment: Check my answer again for an update -- I just posted a bunch of code.  You can get the dynamic behavior you want without hitting the server on every call.  Just pull down the array of possible images once, then generate as much html as you like.

Comment: i checked it in firebug yellostudio.co.uk/temp/indexV2.php

Answer (score 1):

`hover()` takes two function parameters, one for `mouseover` and the other for `mouseout`. You've only supplied the first. You'll need to supply the second to undo the image swapping on `mouseout`.

If you want the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` to be concurrent, don't put the `fadeIn` in the callback of the `fadeOut`. Just make them separate statements:

```
$(this).fadeOut("slow");
$(this).attr({ src: largePath }).fadeIn("slow");
```

The way you have it, the `fadeIn` doesn't start until the `fadeOut` is done. This way, they'll both start and finish at the same time.

Comment: Applying two concurrent animations on one element will not provide a cross-fade effect. Your code will start to fade out but not all the way, then instantly change the image while it's fading out and fade back.

Comment: Hi no Suprises, thanks for your help....

I added the code and it seems to be working however i try and get the fade out bit working and i always get a syntax error and a blank screen...could you shed some light on this?  

Thanks again

Comment: Oh, sorry. joshperry is right: that only works if you have two images and they're positioned absolutely on top of each other.

Comment: Does it make any difference that i am calling it via "rel"?

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest: http://colorpowered.com/blend/

It will do what you are looking to do.

---

**Edit:**
Okay, well, for one, I would definitely change the ajax part of your code to have it return all your images via json (even better I would do it on the back-end, but, I'm not sure how your site is setup). Anyways, it seems like you are fading out your other image unnecessarily. Simply place the color image above the other image with absolute positioning. Maybe your code could look something like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$('.hoverImg').live('mouseover',function() {
   $hovered = $(this);
   var colorPath = $hovered.attr("rel");
   var rndId = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
   var $colorImg = $('<img />');
   $colorImg
       .hide()
       .addClass("fader")
       .attr('src',colorPath)
       .attr('id','img_'+rndId)
       .css({position:'absolute',zIndex:10});
   $hovered.css({zIndex:9}).data('overImgId',rndId).before($colorImg);
   $('#img_'+rndId).stop().fadeIn("slow");
});
$('.hoverImg').live('mouseout',function() {
    var rndId = $(this).data('overImgId')
    $('#img_'+rndId).stop().fadeOut("slow");
});
$.getJSON('random.php',{numBoxes:totalBoxes},function(json) {
    if(json.length > 0) {
        $.each(json,function(i,val) {
            $(val).hide().appendTo('#bg').find('img').addClass('hoverImg');
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php //random.php (really simplified, probably)
if(isset($_GET['numBoxes']) && !empty($_GET['numBoxes'])) {
    /*
        Get all the html stuff you need into an array...
        Could look something like:
        $imgs = array(
            '<div><img src="foo.jpg" rel="color_foo.jpg" /></div>',
            '<div><img src="bar.jpg" rel="color_bar.jpg" /></div>'
        );
    */
    echo json_encode($imgs);
}
```

That should basically work. There might be some typos and stuff in there but, from what I can tell, it should work. Of course, depending on your scenario, you may need to tweak/alter some of this.

Good luck on your project!

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I forgot to add a key part to the PHP code. I added the "rel" attrs to the `<img>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks really useful but i was hoping just to ammend my code as i know i am nearly there... :@)  i hope!

Comment: wow that is totally different to what i have.  I'll try it and see how i get on.  I dont hvae any experience in json

Comment: Is the jquery blend plugin yours?  I just sent you an email.

Comment: Id like to pay you do add your solution as although i hvae it working its very slow and the fade in effect i was hoping for just work.  The fade was working perfectly when i was using the rel attribute to reference the other image but i couldnt get the crossfade happening....

Comment: No, I didn't make the blend plugin that I linked to. It's a pretty nice one though. I won't be needing any sort of payment for any solution I give you on this site. Is what I provided above not working for you?

Comment: NO it wasnt but i could try adding it again now quickly with your ammend?

Comment: Didnt work sorry...i left the code there though if you had time to check it was in place right:
http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/index.php#

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to store the original image path (which is what you want to fade back to on hover out, right), then restore it on the hover out.

```
var $d = $(html).hide().appendTo('#bg').fadeIn('slow');
$('img', $d).hover(function() {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).data('orig', $(this).attr('src') );
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
         $(this).attr({ src: largePath }).fadeIn("slow");
     });
},function() {
    var origPath = $(this).data('orig');
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
         $(this).attr({ src: origPath }).fadeIn("slow");
     });
});
```

Assuming that the "bright" image is used as the src attribute and you use opacity to achieve the effect.

```
var $d = $(html).hide().appendTo('#bg');
$('img',$d).css('opacity',0.33);
           .hover( function() {
               $(this).fadeTo('slow',1.0);
            }, function() {
               $(this).fadeTo('slow',0.33);
            });
```

Comment: Hey thanks tvanfosson, the code you suggested i have just tested and its working but there is a weird flash at the start of the hover and it doesn't cross fade, if you have time to check the link i would appreciate it...

Comment: I didn't think about this but you need to wait until the fadeOut completes before replacing the src attribute.  Otherwise you end up with the new image at full opacity (the flash) before the fadeOut completes.  Do this by moving the change into the fadeOut callback.  Also, have you thought about simply adjusting the opacity between 50% and 100% on hover using the same "bright" image instead of switching between light and dark images.  This might be the "cross fade" effect that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a cross-fade you need two images, one that is fading in, and one that is fading out concurrently. Take a look at a [page I did](http://www.ferraricolor.com) with this effect. The plugin I wrote is right in the page source so you can take a look at it. The two images will need to have `position: absolute;` so that as they cross-fade they can occupy the same area of the page.

And like No Surprises said, you are only supplying a callback to `hover` for the mouse hover, and not the mouse un-hover which is where you would cross-fade back to the original.

This code may work, remember the absolute positioning in your CSS, and you may want to add a CSS class to the backImg, and the images must be in a discrete parent element that the hover event is subscribed on:

```
for (var i=0; i < totalBoxes; i++){
    $.ajax({
        url: "random.php?no=",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $(html)
                .hide()
                .appendTo('#bg')
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .children('img').each(function() {
                    var img = $(this);
                    var largePath = img.attr("rel");
                    var backImg = $("<img src='" + largePath + "'/>");
                    img.after(backImg);

                    img.parent().hover(
                        function() { // over
                            backImg.stop().fadeIn("slow");
                            img.stop().fadeOut("slow");
                        },
                        function() { // out
                            backImg.stop().fadeOut("slow");
                            img.stop().fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                    );
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: could you give me an idea on how to ammend my code to encorporate a mouse out?  Its using the rel attribute to pull in the new image.

Comment: joshperry, thanks for your help on this...i really have spent hours...i have uploaded the code so you can see whats happening...unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: I've added code that may work for you, but I'd still recommend using the more generalized blend plugin in KyleFarris' answer.

Comment: Sorry man, I'd love to help you more, unfortunately this isn't a consultancy site, it's a Q&A site to help people that mostly understand the underlying technology. Code in my answers will rarely work in a cut-n-paste situation and leaves some onus on the asker to mold the solution to fit in their specific implementation.

Comment: I have updated it now and its getting there, just the cross fade bit...and its flashing at the start of the hover instead of fading in over the top...

thanks josh!

Comment: fair do's!  I dont mind paying for a solution...im that fed up with it now

Comment: if you want a cross-fade you HAVE to have two images, one to fadein and one to fadeout, your code is back to attempting to use one image again, see my comments on @No Surprises answer for why this won't work. If you make html that comes back from your server have each img wrapped in a DIV my code my work for you. Really though, just download the blend plugin, it's free.

Comment: Thanks josh, i know im clutching at straws here....its just so frustrating because ive spent days and days figuring getting this far and then i found this forum.  you have been a tremendous help and ill try and figure it out based on your comments...i just thought the whole "rel" attribute was really cool way of doing it.

Thanks again

Comment: Nothing wrong with the rel technique as long as you generate a second image using that url in your script (like mine does). Again, if you modify your ajax response to wrap each img in a div my code may work for you.

Comment: If i get it to print this...

<div class="pf-box">
  <a href="#">
   <div class="black"><img src="'.$image_folder.'/'.$image_name.'.jpg" alt="'.$image_name.'" border="0" /></div>
   <div class="colour"><img src="'.$image_folder.'/'.$image_name.'-c.jpg" alt="'.$image_name.'" border="0" /></div>
  </a>
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using some additional code.  Position the fade-in image on top of the fade-out image, with opacity set to 0.  Add the hover code to the fade-in image (it's on top, so it gets the events).

```
$('#top-image').hover(function() {
$(this).stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
$('#bottom-image').stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);
},
function() {
$(this).stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);
$('#bottom-image').stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
});
```

Both images fade in and out, and with the use of the stop() function, mousing in and out rapidly won't lead to a series of repeated animations.

Comment: Would you be interested in a payment to get this thing working for me?

Comment: I amm not sure how to add your above code into what i have already!

Comment: This is just example code, I just wrote it off the cuff.  Feel free to contact me if you're still stuck...

Comment: just trying one other solution from anotehr user...so lost in this all now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet add:

```
.colour {
  display:none;
}
```

Then make your success function read:

```
var $d = $(html).hide().appendTo('#bg').fadeIn('slow');
$('.pf-box', $d).hover(function() {
  $('.colour', $(this)).fadeIn("slow");      
},function() {
  $('.colour', $(this)).fadeOut("slow");      
});
```

**UPDATE**

To solve the slow loading problem you'll need to have your PHP return an object of all images like so (let's say it's called images.php -- put the code below inside of `<?php ?>`) (you'd want to use json_encode() but he was on an older version of PHP):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{
  {'black' : 'url', 'colour' : 'url'},
  {'black' : 'url2', 'colour' : 'url2'}
}';
```

Then in javascript you want:

```
//generate all the boxes
$.get('images.php',function(data){
  for (var i=0; i < totalBoxes; i++){
      var randomImage = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
      $('<div class="pf-box"><img class="black" src="' + randomImage['black'] + '" /><img class="colour" src="' + randomImage['colour'] + '" /></div>').hide().appendTo('#bg').fadeIn('slow').filter('.colour').css("opacity", 0);
  }
 },'json');

 //add the hover behavior to all the elements
 $('.pf-box').hover(function() {
   $('.colour',$(this)).stop().fadeTo(700, 1);
 },function() {
   $('.colour',$(this)).stop().fadeTo(700, 0);
 });
```

This code should work...but I haven't tested it.  There might be typos.  But this is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks aaron, i tried your method and it didnt work unfortunately. I resorted to my answer below...although its really clunky now...not happty with it :"(

Comment: ok this looks promising, does it loop through the array then regardless of how many are returned?  So if i did a resize function it would loop through the same array and add more?

Comment: Ive given it a go but it doesnt define the source...i checked it in firebug
http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/indexV2.php

Comment: You have a parse error on your images.php page: "syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/sites/yellostudio.co.uk/public_html/temp/images.php on line 3

Comment: <?php 

{ "images" : 
  {
    "black"  : "images/random/1.jpg",
    "colour" : "images/random/1-c.jpg"
  },
  {
    "black"  : "images/random/2.jpg",
    "colour" : "images/random/2-c.jpg"
  }
}

?>

Comment: i just pasted what you put on this post and changed the URLs was that wrong?  Thanks again aaron. You're helping me out no end!

Comment: You've got to echo that...I'll update my post with the exact php

Comment: still nothing:
http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/indexV2.php 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /home/sites/yellostudio.co.uk/public_html/temp/images.php on line 6

Comment: check your images.php code carefully...that error makes no sense in light of what I put up there

Comment: Here is an exact copy...


<?php 

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
  array(
    "black"  : "images/random/1.jpg",
    "colour" : "images/random/1-c.jpg"
  ),
  array(
    "black"  : "images/random/2.jpg",
    "colour" : "images/random/2-c.jpg"
  )
));

?>

Comment: take out the ":" between the key and value and use "=>" instead...just like I have in my post

Comment: I see your error -- looks like you're running an older version of PHP

Comment: Sorry didnt notice that bit had changed....still no go sorry!

http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/temp/indexV2.php

Comment: you need php 5.2 for json_encode() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php  -- but I've updated my post again with manually-created JSON -- try that

Comment: I cant believe your helping me as much as you are...thanks so much...but...

<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{
  {'black' : 'images/random/1.jpg', 'colour' : 'images/random/1-c.jpg'},
  {'black' : 'images/random/2.jpg'', 'colour' : 'images/random/2-c.jpg'}
}';
?>

Comment: looks like you fixed it by moving to php5 -- well, you're really close now.  For some reason jQuery's not interpreting it as a JSON array

Comment: try using $.getJSON instead of $.get (and get rid of the last parameter - json -- from your get call)

Comment: mmm i dont see any images, but im guessing thats because of what you just mentioned. I hvae no knowledge of json sorry!

Comment: Well...you're really close.  Sorry I've got to run at this point but I'll check in later.  Your PHP is good now.  You just need to get the javascript to parse the JSON correctly.

Comment: You know what...I think you may need to send it a JSON object, not an array.  In your PHP change json_encode(yourarrayhere) call to look like this json_encode(yourarrayhere, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)

Comment: get rid of display:none on .colour elements

Comment: get rid of visibility:hidden -- and check out the hover portion of the javascript in my answer.  I've edited it and it now works a bit differently.  Copy it all over.

Comment: Your twirling loading background image is also causing a lot of cpu usage (a steady 100% on an older 2.4 ghz Sempron machine I have) -- you probably want to remove it once the page is done loading.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a problem here...

```
var backImg = $("<img src='" + largePath + "'/>");
```

This isn't a valid selector.  Try this instead:

```
var backImg = $('img[src="' + largePath + '"]');
```

You don't want to use the <> in your selector, and the attribute selector syntax should look like this:  [attr="value"]
You should note that I reversed the use of ' and " in my code - that's just how I do it, it's syntactically identical.  There's nothing wrong with your choice of quotes.

Comment: THanks for your input, i cannot find any reference to backImg